# What is the best level or method for gathering coins?

Tags: skylanders-giants

I'm trying to help my son upgrade some of his Skylanders figures, and wondering which level in *Skylanders Giants* is the best for gathering coins. Alternately, is there some other method for quickly gathering coins, such as the Battle modes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Kaos's Castle really good for gathering coin, especially if you have 3 or 4 wealth wheels in the luck o tron

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the back of the ship, where the pirate is, there are elemental doors. When you match the element all the way through, you get a nice handful of dough. That's what I do to get more money.